# creating a class method for a active record attribute like has_attached_file

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have seen in paperclip gem `has_attached_file :avatar`.

How can I create a method like this for models?

My objective is whenever i define attribute like `custom_method :attribute` i can run some active operation the data of attribute on active record callbacks like save and delete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just a class method.

```
def self.custom_method(attribute)
  before_save do
    do_stuff_with(attribute)
  end

  define_method "do_stuff_with_#{attribute}" do
    do_stuff_with(attribute)
  end

  do_other_stuff
end
```

You can either add it to your `ApplicationRecord` for it to be available everywhere or add it to a `Concern`/`Mixin`/`Module` that you can include when you want to use it.